# EWS query result wierdness

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've got a strange problem with EWS.  I am writing a console app which queries my inbox for messages with a subject containing 'Ref:' which is absolutely fine, I get a connection no problem, run the query, get some results.  but strangely it is only returning messages that are from internal senders, any messages sent from outside the exchange organisation do not appear in the results.

ultimately I am going to be using a service account to connect to various mailboxes and find various emails with certain references in the subject....

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?  I've gone over it and over it and can't find any reason why it's doing it.

It's Exchange 2010 SP2

```
        ExchangeService exchService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        exchService.Url = new System.Uri("https://xxx.xxxxxxxxx.co.uk/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        exchService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        var userMailbox = new Mailbox("xxxx@xxxx.co.uk");
        var inboxFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, userMailbox);
        String qString = "subject:\"Ref:\"";
        ItemView view = new ItemView(20);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Id);
        try
        {
            FindItemsResults<Item> results = exchService.FindItems(inboxFolder, qString, view);
            if (results.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Item item in results.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
                    if (item is EmailMessage)
                    {
                        EmailMessage bindMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(exchService, item.Id.ToString());
                        String sender = bindMessage.Sender.Address.ToString();
                        String Body = bindMessage.Body.Text.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Sender: " + sender);
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a SearchFilter instead and then compare the results ?

Comment: thanks glen,  i'll give that a try when i get to the office..  cheers.chris.

Comment: FYI, Our exchange topology is pretty complex,  there are 6 servers,  2 with Client access role installed..  i queried against a different server after chatting to our sys admins and got the results i expected, Thanks for your help though.  Cheers. Chris